# How can I create thread on NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, signal-processing, real-time

I added hpf filter to this implemetation of audio-echo https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master .
I need to use as new process for hpf for convolution because there are packets loss after a few seconds and no more signal on output.
I tried to find example on this code of  producerConsumerQueue that use thread but I didn't find it

Comment: new process or new thread?

Comment: I need a high performance, I think that thread @pskink

Comment: so you have [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)

Comment: I assumed that audio_record and audio_play this also threads but I didn't find this on code @pskink

Comment: Can you help me ? @pskink